# Функция getenv

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, нужно написать собственную версию функции getenv, которая получает переменные окружения.
Вот то что я нашёл, мне кажется это всего лишь мелкий пример, да и тот ни о чём.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *s;
   s = getenv("COMSPEC"); /* получить параметр среды */
   printf("Командный процессор находится: %s\n",s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Дмитрий26, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: А эта функция вас чем не устраивает?

Comment: Спасибо, большое.
Прошу прощение за бестактность.

Comment: Я просто хотел проконсультироваться с опытным человеком, по этому поводу, по-моему это не то что нужно по заданию.

Answer (score 3):

В **/usr/include/unistd.h** есть определение

```
extern char **environ;
```

Массив завершается NULL.

А можно так

```
int main (int ac, char *av[], char *env[]) { ... }
```

env это массив указателей (аналогичный av[]) на переменные среды, последний элемент - NULL.

Берете и печатаете, смотрите и программируете свой вариант.

**UPDATE**

Кстати, в Linux в оглавлении **/proc/PID/** есть файл **environ**, в котором содержатся текущие переменные среды процесса PID (для своего (текущего) процесса это **/proc/self/environ**).

Т.е. можно (если прав хватает) прочесть и чужую среду.

Comment: я однозначно не минусовал.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Дмитрий, для совместимости с Windows (проверял в MinGW) лучше всегда включайте stdlib.h для доступа к extern char \*\*environ.

Comment: В смысле, я не совсем понял, как так с Windows?
Данная работа рассчитана ведь только на Linux.

Comment: @Дмитрий26, понимаете, понятие environment есть во многих ОС. Поэтому я и вспомнил про Винду (к другим у меня сейчас доступа нет). 

Думаю, может полезно будет. Вы когда напишите свой **getenv()** попробуйте его на чем только получится. Появится некоторый опыт писать переносимые программы.

Comment: @avp,спасибо огромное, мне как раз винда ближе и роднее будет.

Comment: @avp,дело в том что мне на Windows писать даже удобней, потому что я столкнулся с горой проблем при установке линукса через Virtual Box

Comment: Про гору проблем с Linux на VBox уже не помню. За день, наверное, Ubuntu 10.04 поставил и настроил. Ставил с образа ISO, а не реального драйва. На другой машине (с XP) Xubuntu 11.04 поставил и интерфейс (Xfce) в ней мне даже больше понравился.

Сетевой адаптер в VBox надо делать bridged (Сетевой мост) и в Win 7 (забыл вот уже название) в чем-то типа firewall разрешить всю активность по максимуму.

@Дмитрий, Linux лучше все-таки добейте. Многие вещи близкие к системе в винде своеобразны (а про кодировки русского консоль/файлы я вообще молчу).

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать переменную environ, являющуюся указателем на массив указателей на строки, содержащие значения переменных среды. Последние представляют собой пару переменная-значение, разделенные знаком "=". Перебираете последовательно эти строки, парсите их и получаете то, что стоит до знака равенства. Далее сравниваете его с именем искомой переменной и, если они совпадают, возвращаете указатель на часть строки после равенства или, лучше, создаете новый строковый буфер соответственной длины, копируете туда эту часть строки и возвращаете его адрес.

Comment: Не, мне на минусы конечно наплевать, но хотелось бы понять, ПОЧЕМУ два правильных и по сути одинаковых ответа так отмечены ???

Comment: выровнял :) действительно не честно выходит...

Comment: а кому минусовали-то?

Comment: Я минусовал. Ответы не совсем правильные, т.к. а) предлагают использовать нестандартные вещи (unistd.h (POSIX) и третий параметр в main (MS)), при наличии стандартной функции getenv, б) поощряют велосипедописательство.

Comment: вы вопрос внимательно читали? Или русский плохо знаете? В никсах environ и unistd.h - самые обычные и стандартные вещи. Не знаете, лучше молчите. По поводу велосипедов: это очевидно учебное задание и как таковое очень полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил таким образом:

```
/* environ.c */
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

extern char ** environ; /* Environment itself */

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "environ: Too few arguments\n");

        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: environ <variable>\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        if (!strncmp (environ[i], argv[1], strlen (argv[1])))
        {
            printf ("'%s' found\n", environ[i]);
            exit (0);
        }   
    }
    printf ("'%s' not found\n", argv[1]);
    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: @Дмитрий26, пока еще вряд ли это правильная программа. Попробуйте вызвать ее, например, так :

    ./environ P


Еще один тест :

    ./environ PATH=

Не думаю, что у Вас на самом деле есть такие переменные. Т.е. сравнивать при поиске надо более изощренно.

И потом, от Вас (судя по вопросу) хотели функцию (видимо отдельно компилируемую) **аналогичную** getenv().

Но, не расстраивайтесь. Вы на правильном пути. Главное нашли и можете читать массив этих переменных, а уж правильно сравнить получится.